# Css pseudo-elements alignment

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, pseudo-element

I have the following fiddle, not able to align the image using `:after` in my case, it is not as bad as in fiddle, but it is touching the horizontal line more towards the bottom of the box foreach div instead of aligning with the text inside div.

http://jsfiddle.net/pT7vX/

Comment: Down voted? what is the reason? don't just do that because you can.And not completely understanding the question...

Answer (score 1):

Just change your position to relative, and tone down the padding. At least I assume this is more what you're after.

```
div.lnk:after {
        background:image;
        content: ">";
        position:relative;
        padding:5px;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pT7vX/1/

hope this helps.

Comment: For the normal content like '>', this works but I have an image in the background, also the arrows need to be in a single vertical column(vertically aligned), not sure how to place an absolute path for any image in the fiddle...

Comment: screen shot it, what you got, and what you want.